# refactor angular ng-resource error handling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

Warning: coffeescript ahead.

I have multiple controllers with various ngresource functions like so:

```
app.controller 'usersCtrl', ($scope, $state, $filter, $flash, $api) ->

$scope.saveUser = ->
    $scope.spinner = true
    $api.User.save($scope.user).$promise.then ((response) ->
       ....
    ), (error)
       $scope.spinner = false
       if error.code = 400
          $flash.create('warning', error.message)
       else if error.code = 500
          $flash.create('danger', error.message)

$scope.updateFoo = ->
    $scope.spinner = true
    $api.Foo.update(foo: $scope.foo).$promise.then ((response) ->
       ....
    ), (error) ->
       $scope.spinner = false
       if error.code = 400
          $flash.create('warning', error.message)
       else if error.code = 500
          $flash.create('danger', error.message)
```

Given that I'm using virtually the same error handling code across dozens of functions, how do I refactor the code so I can reuse across multiple functions.

Comment: Use service for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about refactoring the error handler into a function?

```
errorHandler = (error) ->
  $scope.spinner = false
  if error.code = 400
    $flash.create('warning', error.message)
  else if error.code = 500
    $flash.create('danger', error.message)
```

Then use it like this:

```
$scope.saveUser = ->
    $scope.spinner = true
    $api.User.save($scope.user).$promise.then ((response) ->
       ....
    ), errorHandler
```